# groupby.apply change original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I do `df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: create_delta(x, 7, 'rank'))`

where

```
def create_delta_days(df,interval,col):
    ----df['new column 1'] = do some work here----
    ----df['new column 2'] = do some work here----
    return df
```

But this prints the groupby object showing the changes. How do I incorporate those changes and change my original df dataframe?

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Don't override the variables names:

```
def create_delta_days(x, interval, col):
    ----x['new column 1'] = do some work here----
    ----x['new column 2'] = do some work here----
    return x
```